# Pointer outputs

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm just trying to understand the difference in how you output pointers.

let's say I have:

```
int x = 100;
int*p = &x;
```

what would each of the following do?

```
cout << p << endl;
cout << *p << endl;
cout << &p << endl;
```

Comment: Why not ask the compiler?

Comment: Looks like a homework or test question.

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues, just compiling and running can tell you a lot, especially using the `sizeof` function.

Comment: If it is a hardware type of company, I would be surprised if this kind of question is asked.  The C++ questions may not even occur.  Expect MATLAB or LabVIEW oriented questions though.  If you know Verilog, VHDL, and/or SystemVerilog, I can see questions about them occurring too.

Comment: They do some programming too. Mostly scripting though. This is just in case a pointer question comes up.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << p << endl;  // prints the adress p points to,
                    // that is the address of x in memory
cout << *p << endl; // prints the value of object pointed to by p,
                    // that is the value of x
cout << &p << endl; // prints the address of the pointer itself
```

Comment: I didn't say how this will be printed but what it does

Comment: @lizusek: Was not a criticism, just wanted to add that info.

Answer (score 3):

`int*p = &x;` creates a pointer, `p`, which points to the variable `x`. A pointer is actually implemented as a variable which holds the memory address which it is pointing to. In this case, you will get the following. For the purposes of this example, assume that x is stored at 0x1000 and p is stored at 0x1004:

- `cout << p << endl;` will print the address of `x` (0x1000).
- `cout << *p << endl;` will dereference the pointer, and hence will print the value of x (100).
- `cout << &p << endl;` takes the address of `p`. Remember that pointers are simply variables in their own right. For this reason, it will print 0x1004.

Comment: Note that the address of `x` is not always `0x1000`, the size and value of the pointer varies by system. Sames goes for `&p`, size and value varies.

Comment: +1 if you fix the implication that the addresses are somehow predictable

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit better?